# How do I safely "copy" my gpg keys from kgpg on Linux to an Android app like openkeychain?

Tags: security, encryption, file-transfer

The title says most of it. I have a key pair setup on kgpg running under Kubuntu 12.04 Linux on my notebook. My smartphone (Galaxy S3) has no SD card slot.

I want to be able to transfer files between my notebook and my smartphone. Since I don't have a card reader for the phone yet, I figured I could do it using email or dropbox.

But both of those ways expose the files to other people and I would prefer they were encrypted.

The first file I want to send is my password vault from my notebook and although it's encrypted itself, I really need to be sure it's locked tight before it gets anywhere near the Internet.

Comment: Why do you need a card reader for a phone without an SD Card slot? Just hook it up via usb. There's a question on here somewhere helping you with that if you have issues. On a side note, my S3 has a card Slot, so I'm rather mystified why yours doesn't.

Comment: @ionree - Mine doesn't seem to have an SD slot per http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201409/20140905012624453/SPT_SPH-L710T_Galaxy_S3_English_User_Manual_KK_NE5_F3_AC.pdf But just plugging it into a USB cable was entirely too simple to occur to me LOL. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main objective here is to keep the file local in order to minimize the risk of an outsider deliberately stealing your keys.

**Method 1 (recommended)**

Hook up your phone via the USB charging cable that came with it. In order to do this, plug in the small micro-USB connector into the respective slot on the bottom of your phone. Then plug in the large USB2 connector into your computer.

You should now have a notification on your phone prompting you to enable mass storage. If you do not see this notification, download and install the [Samsung USB Drivers](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.dohttp://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117). Now do enable mass storage.

Open the device with your computers file manager and copy the desired file over.

**Method 2 (potentially less secure)**

Some apps allow you to run an FTP Server on your phone. This allows you to remotely access your phone from within your local network. The downside is that allows any other machine on the network to grab the data while it is being sent.

From my experience, [ES File Explorer](https://www.google.ch/urlhttps://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dcom.estrongs.android.pop%26hl%3Dde%26referrer%3Dutm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dorganic%2526utm_term%253Des%2Bfile%2Bexplorer%26pcampaignid%3DAPPU_1_ODOSVqr5C4PXUcyskcgP&ved=0ahUKEwiq9bCwhZ_KAhWDaxQKHUxWBPkQ8oQBCB8wAA&usg=AFQjCNFKBdA2Jde2hODyBLnT7i5FmSTjkg&sig2=_mlHuq6ER6aCr7o7DZjI2w) does the best job at this, supplying a ton of other useful features as well.

Once you have installed the app, launch it and press the Menu key. Scroll down to "Remote Manager" and hit "Turn On". Type the supplied address into your computers file manager. Now copy the desired files to the desired destination.

**Method 3 (potentially less secure)**

If your computer supports Bluetooth, you can exchange files using it. Again, the downside is that allows any other machine on the network to grab the data while it is being sent.

Turn on Bluetooth on both your phone and your computer, and set one of them to be visible. Then connect to it from the other machine. You will have to confirm the connection, and potentially type in a code displayed in the other machine.

You can now open the device in your computers file manager and copy the desired files to the desired destination.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - which should have worked. This would have been ideal - if it worked. On my notebook, the device keeps trying to connect using each possible slot - or something and fails after many attempts. I looked at https://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-enabled-devices-to-work-with-ubuntu and http://gunavara.blogspot.com/2012/11/samsung-galaxy-s3-vs-ubuntu-1204.html and have tried some of their suggestions, but it still doesn't connect.

Comment: I just ordered a USB adapter http://www.ebay.com/itm/HDTV-Adapter-OTG-TF-Card-Reader-HDMI-Connection-For-Samsung-Galaxy-Note-2-S3-S4-/331578296112?hash=item4d339b4730:g:IDAAAOSwBahVdxoL Hopefully that will work. I'm also wondering if there is some sort of internal SD card slot. There isn't one on the outside of the case.

Comment: @Joe - On the top of your phone, you should have a small cutout in the plastic cover to pull said cover off. Underneath the cover should be SIM-Card, SD-Card and Battery slots, unless you are on some weird version of the S3. You can find details on page 2 of the manual mentioned in you comment above. Also, you shouldn't need any sort of adapter, just hook the changing cable up to your PC and phone.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more details and additional methods.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to accept this answer. Although it works, I ended up installing KDE Connect and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

DropBox is pretty safe for this purpose. It is [encrypted](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/27):

> Dropbox uses Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)/Transport Layer Security (TLS)
>   to protect data in transit between Dropbox apps and our servers; it's
>   designed to create a secure tunnel protected by 128-bit or higher
>   Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) encryption.

Comment: With Dropbox, I'm not so concerned with the transport - although that's great to know. I'm concerned that once I put anything there, it's there forever - at least in backups and may eventually get hacked like everything else. I will use dropbox for less sensitive things or if I can get gpg working on both ends to add another layer of protection.

Comment: The problem with any cloud service is that although the actual data is theoretically secure, someone might be able to guess the password and gain access to the files. This happened for example when a hacker grabbed nudes from celebrities' iCloud accounts.